# How to return max counts per another node's properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to calculate how many times a composer's pieces of music were performed per decade, then return only the one piece with the most performances per decade.

This cypher does everything except filter all but the highest counts per decade.

```
match (c:Composer)-[:CREATED_BY]-(w:Work)<-[*..2]-(prog:Program) 
WHERE c.lastname =~ '(?i).*stravinsky.*' 
WITH w.title AS Title, prog.title AS Program, LEFT(prog.date, 3)+"0" AS Decade
RETURN Decade, Title, COUNT(Program) AS Total
ORDER BY Decade, Total DESC, Title
```

I've been banging my head for hours with variations on this but can't find the solution.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, what you get as a result from the query, and what you're expecting?  In particular, I'm confused about why you're doing `[*..2]` to `Program` nodes.  Why not just one?

Comment: There's another node between them for the performance itself, but we're not interested in it for this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to return what you're looking for but it can probably be improved.

```
MATCH (c:Composer)-[r:CREATED_BY]-(w:Work)<-[*..2]-(prog:Program)
WHERE c.lastname =~ '(?i).*stravinsky.*'
WITH LEFT(prog.date, 3)+"0" AS Decade, w.title AS Title, COUNT(prog.title) AS Total
ORDER BY Decade, Total DESC, Title
RETURN Decade, HEAD(COLLECT(Total)) AS Total, HEAD(COLLECT(Title)) AS Title
ORDER BY Decade
```

It only returns one result from each decade but doesn't take ties into account, so it feels a little incomplete to me. I'll think about how to do that and edit if I come up with something good.

I used this string with http://graphgen.neoxygen.io to generate sample data locally.

```
(c:Composer {firstname: firstName, lastname: lastName} *10)<-[:CREATED_BY *n..1]-(w:Work {title: progLanguage} *75)<-[:PERFORMED *n..1]-(prog:Program {title: catchPhrase, date: date} *400)
```

**VICTORY EDIT**

This is the raw version of the above query that will show multiple Works when there are ties.

```
MATCH (c:Composer)-[r:CREATED_BY]-(w:Work)<-[*..2]-(prog:Program)
WHERE c.lastname =~ '(?i).*stravinsky.*'
WITH LEFT(prog.date, 3)+"0" AS Decade, w.title AS Title, COUNT(prog.title) AS Total
ORDER BY Decade, Total DESC, Title
WITH Decade, Title, Total, HEAD(COLLECT(Total)) AS PerformedTotal
WITH Decade, [title in COLLECT(Title) WHERE Total = PerformedTotal] as Title, Total, PerformedTotal
ORDER BY PerformedTotal DESC
return Decade, HEAD(COLLECT(PerformedTotal)) as Totals, HEAD(COLLECT(Title)) as Titles
ORDER BY Decade
```

I feel like it should be possible to refactor it but I can't seem to simplify it.

I have a ton of notes about the process of writing this answer. Even if it's not exactly what you're looking for, here's the TLDR cause it was still interesting.

- Get rid of that fuzzy search if you can, find a way to index that property or use an external index like Elasticsearch. You take a massive performance hit when you use that regex.
- There's a bug in Neo4j 2.2.M02 that makes the query crash if `<-[*..2]-` is changed to practically anything else. If you set the Cypher Query  Planner to `Cypher 2.1`, performance is best if that very first line is `MATCH (c:Composer)-[r:CREATED_BY]-(w)<-[r2:REL_TYPE]-(prog)`. Only use a label on that first node to help the `WHERE` do its job. Always always always use node and rel identifiers.
- Cypher has some surprising behavior. That whole `[title in COLLECT(Title) WHERE Total = PerformedTotal]` is using variables from later in that same line. If I pull them out, it crashes.

More surprising behavior was that it hasn't been possible to refactor the way I'd expect. I'd expect to do this but can't:

```
MATCH (c:Composer)-[r:CREATED_BY]-(w:Work)<-[*..2]-(prog:Program)
WHERE c.lastname =~ '(?i).*stravinsky.*'
WITH LEFT(prog.date, 3)+"0" AS Decade, w.title AS Title, COUNT(prog.title) AS Total
ORDER BY Decade, Total DESC, Title
WITH Decade, [title in COLLECT(Title) WHERE Total = HEAD(COLLECT(Total))] as Title, Total, HEAD(COLLECT(Total)) AS PerformedTotal
ORDER BY PerformedTotal DESC
return Decade, HEAD(COLLECT(PerformedTotal)) as Totals, HEAD(COLLECT(Title)) as Titles
ORDER BY Decade
```

**ANOTHER EDIT: HOW TO POSSIBLY SPEED IT UP**

If you have a few potential paths your query may take but you want to avoid `[*..2]`, you may be able to speed things up a bit by giving it specifics about the paths it should take when trying to find a match. Whether or not this is faster really depends on how many branches it can take that will be dead ends. If you can give it just two or three paths so it can completely ignore half a dozen other relationships, it will probably offset the filtering and things that happen later on. Of course, if the paths are complicated enough, this might be more trouble than it's worth.

You should pop this into the neo4j-shell and prepend `PROFILE`, add a semi-colon to the end, and look at the number of database accesses to determine which is best for your dataset.

```
MATCH (c:Composer)-[r:CREATED_BY]-(w)
WHERE c.lastname =~ '(?i).*Denesik.*'
OPTIONAL MATCH (w)-[r2:CONNECTED_TO]-(this_node)<-[r3:ONE_MORE]-(prog1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w)<-[r4:PERFORMED]-(prog2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w)-[r5:THIS_REL]->(this_node)-[r6:AGAIN_WITH_THE_RELS]->(prog3)
WITH FILTER(program in [prog1, prog2, prog3] WHERE program IS NOT NULL) AS progarray, w.title AS Title
UNWIND(progarray) as prog
WITH LEFT(prog.date, 3)+"0" AS Decade, COUNT(prog.title) AS Total, Title
ORDER BY Decade, Total DESC, Title
WITH Decade, Title, Total, HEAD(COLLECT(Total)) AS PerformedTotal
WITH Decade, [title in COLLECT(Title) WHERE Total = PerformedTotal] as Title, Total, PerformedTotal
ORDER BY PerformedTotal DESC
return Decade, HEAD(COLLECT(PerformedTotal)) as Totals, HEAD(COLLECT(Title)) as Titles
ORDER BY Decade;
```

The trickiest part of this is that if we reuse the `prog` variable, it's going to drag the results from each OPTIONAL MATCH into the next one, essentially trying to filter, and we won't get completely separate paths. (Why we're able to reuse `w` is sort of beyond me right now...) That's OK, though. We take the results, put them into an array, filter the empty results, then unwind it back to a single variable containing all the valid results. After that, we continue as normal.

In my tests, it seems like this can be significantly faster with the right dataset. YMMV.

Comment: This does seem to work. I have to verify against the raw data, but that'll take a while. Thank you so much.

The fuzzy search is needed for now, as we're still cleaning and merging the data, which is extensive. Performance at the time isn't an issue (yet).

Am I missing something about <-[*..2]-? There's another node (possibly many branches but only one layer) between them that we want to ignore for this query. I only want to count the Program nodes. Maybe I'm wrong about this?

Comment: Awesome! I misread it at first as "this does not seem to work." Haha. If there is no direct line between Program and Work, the [*..2] is necessary. There are ways to limit it that might help if you have other relationships that you don't want it to follow, I'll edit my response in a bit to see if I can give some examples.

Comment: I am most appreciative of your help.

Comment: I was originally trying tricks with LIMIT 1 in the initially conditions, then hoping I could simply use LIMIT 5 to show the top 5 performances, etc. but it never worked as desired.  

As for [*..2], I thought this means the nodes on either side are up to 2 relationships away (which they are, there's another node in the schema). I don't understand "no direct line" btw Program & Work. Do you mean a single relationship? When I explicitely referenced the relationships and middle node, and removed the labels it ran 3x faster :) thanks for that!

Comment: I'll be able to type up some details soon. Really glad it's all working for you, though! I spent almost two hours figuring it out, it was a tough one but a lot of fun and I identified a bug in the process! Very worthwhile.

Comment: Just added notes about how to possibly speed it up.