# Neo4J - How to Limit Results by WHERE Clause and AGGREGATION

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using Neo4J and have ran a query obtaining the universities in the **South of England** and which is a **Sport University**.

However I am having trouble *Limiting* the results.

What I want is to Limit the results to only show the University with the most ***LIKES*** (in the type column).

For example, in the results below it should only show **Portsmouth University**, not **Brighton University**.

So, what I would like is only three rows showing the WENT_TO, LIKES and DISLIKES of the university with the greatest LIKES.

[image: The Query Ran]

[image: Results Returned from Query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I hope it works, I haven't tested it. It should return only one row, because I put all the counts into a map (maybe you have to add `DISTINCT`).

```sql
MATCH (sportUni:Speciality {title: "Sporty University"})-[:SPECIALISES_IN]-(uni)-[:IS_LOCATED_IN_THE]-(locality:Region {title: "South England"}),
(uni)-[l:LIKES]-(),
(uni)-[d:DISLIKES]-(),
(uni)-[w:WENT_TO]-()
WITH DISTINCT sportUni, locality, uni, count(l) as likes, count(d) AS dislikes, count(w) AS wentto
ORDER BY likes DESC
RETURN head(collect(sportUni)) AS sportUni,
head(collect(locality)) AS locality,
head(collect(uni)) AS uni,
head(collect({LIKES: likes, DISLIKES: dislikes, WENT_TO: wentto})) AS count
```

EDIT: syntax correction

**EDIT2:** Now, with a bit of research I adapted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850600/how-to-return-max-counts-per-another-nodes-properties), and it worked with a small sample query. Though, it looks not too elegant.

Comment: It says there is an error message `Invalid input ''': expected whitespace, an identifier` at RETURN sportUni, locality, uni, **{**'LIKES': count(likes),

Comment: But it doesn't work either. It's a bit tricky with `count` and `max`, I was a bit too fast with my answer. But I'm on it.

Comment: I have made some chnages and got this so far:

`MATCH (sportUni:Speciality {title: "Acadmeic University"})-[:SPECIALISES_IN]-(uni)-[:IS_LOCATED_IN_THE]-(locality:Region {title: "South England"}),
(uni)-[likes:LIKES]-(), (uni)-[dislikes:DISLIKES]-()
WITH sportUni, locality, uni, likes, dislikes
RETURN sportUni, locality, uni, count(DISTINCT likes) AS NoOfLikes, count(DISTINCT dislikes) AS NoOfDislikes, sum(NoOfLikes+NoOfDislikes) AS BOB`

Which gives me number of likes and dislikes of each uni. The sum doesn't work in the example, do you know why?

Comment: Maybe at this point it doesn't know the identifiers. Try to replace it with `count(DISTINCT likes) + count(DISTINCT dislikes)`. And I updated my answer again.